# Terminating app 'NSRangeException', index 2 beyond bounds for empty array' Loading images from parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

```
  if( screenHeight > 480 && screenHeight < 667 )
    {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Iphone5"];
        [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objectsfive, NSError *error) {
            if (!error)
            {
                        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu photos for iphone 5.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
                        self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:objectsfive.count];

                // Do something with the found objects
                for (PFObject *objectfive in objectsfive)
                {
                    PFFile *thumbnails = [objectfive objectForKey:@"Images"];
                    [thumbnails getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                        if (!error)
                        {
                            [self.images addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
        NSLog(@"iPhone 5/5s");
    }
```

Hi, I'm new to iOS.The code works till `self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:objectsfive.count];`. After that it says terminating app.Tried NSLog and checked the count of the array.It loaded 4 images and showed count as 4.Kindly suggest what have i done wrong.

Thanks.

LOG:

> 2015-03-19 11:07:15.868[16716:107177] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[**NSArrayM
>   objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ce5f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010397ebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000103bd0f33 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 227     3
>
>   0x000000010220415d __19-[Home changeImage]_block_invoke + 125     4
>
>   UIKit                               0x0000000104757362
>   +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:]
>   + 473     5   UIKit                               0x000000010475767a +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:] + 55     6
>
>   0x0000000102203f8e -[Home changeImage] + 462  7   Foundation
>
>   0x00000001035382b4 __NSFireTimer + 83     8   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000103c4df64
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 20    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c4db25
>   __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045     10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c10e5d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901    11  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000103c10486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470     12  GraphicsServices
>   0x00000001076e39f0 GSEventRunModal + 161  13  UIKit
>   0x00000001046e5420 UIApplicationMain + 1282   14
>   0x0000000102204943 main + 115     15  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000105aee145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you share the exact log for "terminating app"?

Comment: I'm not sure if `initWithCapacity:` is causing the crash. The log appears to be pointing towards `objectAtIndex:` method called from with-in your `changeImage` method. You should review that to trace the error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.The changeImage method does transition among the array of images.any suggestion on how to check images are there in self.images ?.

Comment: You can see the content of `self.images` in the debugger. 1. Hover over `self.images` to view the content. 2. Use `po self.images` debugger command. 3. Use console/debugger's "Variables View" to see the content of `self.images`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks mustafa.at times its running smoothly.then it occurs with out modifying code.wondering why !

Comment: "at times its running smoothly" -- that's one of the most annoying type of situations. There can be multiple reasons for it. You'll just have to debug and see what are the different variables/conditions that are affecting the program execution. 1. Check your data. 2. Check to make sure that it's not related to how you're managing threads i.e. if you're using background thread, make sure that you're updating the UI in main thread, etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again.Tried changing the  self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:objectsfive.count]; to self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithCapacity:objectsfive.count]; and it worked. arrayWithCapacity solved the exception from occuring.